# How to bypass CORS in ajax call in your localhost when working with Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I have been unable to make a successful call to a URL endpoint due to CORS issues. When I installed a CORS chrome extension, the request went through and returned a valid response with no issues. This is the code below and how can I bypass this CORS error?

```
     const url="http://staging1...";
     let data = { 'encrypted request payload'};
     let fetchData = {
     method:'POST',
     body: data,
     headers: new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
   }

  fetch(url, fetchData)
  .then(function(response)){
  console.log(response);
 }
```

The response from the above code

> Fetch API cannot load
>   http://staging1....
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Only way around it is to have them set the headers for you or you run a proxy on your server.

Comment: Thank you because I came to understand that the site that gives the data is the one that grants the access.